# Sharepoint list adapter in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, ssis

First off, I would like to say that I am very new to `SharePoint` and `SSIS`.

I'm trying to create an `SSIS` package in `VS2010` that fetches rows from a remote SQL server and pushes it to a (also remote) Sharepoint Library.

So far, I managed to install and use the Business Intelligence to design the SSIS package on my VS2010 (thx to SQL server 2012 Standard 180-trial version).
I've also found out about the SharePoint List Adapters, but from what I've read, they are only usable in VS2008.

So, I want to find out if:

```
1. Is it possible to achieve this (SQL -> SSIS Package -> Upload/Push to Sharepoint)
2. Can I use SSIS SharePoint Tools in VS2010?
3. (Edit! Important) Is uploading Shared Documents in SharePoint Library achieved in the same way as publishing lists ?
```

I've found a (not so pleasing) answer to my #1 question, and it's from 2011, so I hope maybe some solution has come up since then: [Sharepoint Development in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557861/sharepoint-development-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know much about SSIS.

However, if SSIS lets you "run a custom piece of code for each SQL returned row", you could then use the SharePoint 2010 [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539976.aspx) to create a SharePoint list item on a remote server for each SQL row.

This *doesn't* require SharePoint to be fully installed on the machine running the SSIS code. It only requires a couple of DLLs, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`. You can copy these from a SharePoint server (located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI) or, I believe, you can install the [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b4579045-b183-4ed4-bf61-dc2f0deabe47).

Comment: thanks for the quick response and the link. Upon reading your comment I realized I made a confusion from the start, and raises another (important) question: 
Is uploading Shared Documents in SharePoint Library achieved in the same way as publishing lists ?

Comment: If you want to create documents in a document library, there's some code you might try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847935/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-list-from-client-side-object-model).

Comment: Yes, SSIS does allow to create custom Script tasks. 
Also, do you think (SP2010 Web Services) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814  might also be of help? I just ran across them, but didn't had time to study more thoroughly

Comment: I think you could go either way - I'd use the OM myself unless I ran into something it couldn't do. There's some discussion [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/24/deciding-which-sharepoint-2010-api-to-use-jim-crowley.aspx).